# "command not found" on all packages installed by Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I am on a new M2 Apple computer. I'm using homebrew (as one does). When I install literally anything with homebrew, I can't access it via the command line.

For example, if I run `brew install nvm` and run `nvm -v` I get `command not found: nvm`

This is universal behavior for everything I try to install.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get *"Not found"* error on Linux or macOS, you need to look at your `PATH` to see where your shell is looking:

```
echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin            # sample output
```

That gives you a list of directories in which your shell will try to find the command you typed. Your `nvm` command cannot be in any directory on your `PATH` because it was not found.

So, you need to find `nvm` and tell the shell where it is. As you installed `nvm` via **homebrew**, it will be in

```
/opt/hombrew/bin/nvm        # Apple Silicon, or "/usr/local/bin" Intel Macs
```

You can check this by running:

```
ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/nvm
```

Now you need to tell your shell to look in `/opt/homebrew/bin` if it wants to find `nvm` or any other **homebrew** package. This is a part of the **homebrew** installation which you must have missed. You need to do:

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

---

In general, if you have problems with **homebrew**, you should run:

```
brew doctor
```

and follow the good doctor's advice.